# Bat, How to prevent environment variables leaking into parent process

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a bat file similiar to this

```
rem build.bat
rem add visual studio paths to env
call "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64

cl.exe blabla
```

After running it a couple of times I get the error `The input line is too long.` because vcvarsall.bat seems to append to the path variables every time I invoke the script

I invoke the script with `build.bat`

I thought that the environment variables should not be saved between runs. Is there any way to make the variables not leak into the calling cmd shell?

Comment: The command, adding the visual studio path to the `%PATH%` environment variable, what does that command look like?

Comment: @Dominique `call "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should localize the environment of your batch file by putting [`setlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) at the beginning and [`endlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html) at the end (the latter may be omitted as it executes implicitly on exiting the script).

Answer (score 4):

You could start the build.bat in a child process.

`cmd /c build.bat`

Variables in the parent process aren't affected by a child process.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, environment variables don't get saved between runs, which is correct, but a "run" in this case is not the "run" of the batchfile, but of the command prompt in which you run the batchfile.

In my opinion, you have opened a command prompt. In there you launch the "build.bat" file, over and over again.

However, if you would launch the batchfile from outside of a command prompt (like double-clicking from the Windows explorer), this problem should not appear.